# Advancing PCB Design Knowledge: Seeking Resources for EMC, Analog Signals, RF and More

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, electromagnetism, kicad

I'm designing 4 layer, 2 sided pcbs with MCU, radio module, digital sensors (i2c, UART..) and analog ones (4-20 mA, 0-10V). All on an average budget of 50 uW. Everything is quite slow here, 115200 baud is lightning fast for my applications. I use KiCad. I've picked up all I know from watching consultants do the job for me at first and then mainly by just doing it myself. My company has sold some 500 hundred copies of my boards. I have a university background, but not in electronics. I know math, basic electronics, Kirchoff, a little bit of electrodynamics and then some. There is no one else at my company that knows hardware or electronics.

I'm trying to argue the case for learning a bit more of the theory on the job and I think I have quite a strong case. What resources would you recommend in the following areas for a novice that's eager to learn? Time will be a limiting factor for my excursions so I'm looking for the low hanging fruit and perhaps not the deepest of dives in each area at first.

1. EMC theory
2. EMC tips and tricks in practice
3. RF, module integration on PCB
4. Analog signal integrity
5. Li-ion and LTC battery management
6. General best practices for PCB design
7. Your suggestion?

I read the Muse and listen to Embedded FM and The EEcosystem on my commute, although I mainly want something a bit deeper this time, similar material is also welcome!

Thank you!

Comment: This question is very broad, but for some books I would recommend that cover some of those topics: Electromagnetic Compatability Engineering by Henry Ott, Signal and Power Integrity by Eric Bogatin, and High-Speed Digital Design by Howard Johnson. All of these authors have personal webpages that also have a wealth of information.